# EF5 error: Cascading foreign key FK_... where the referencing column X is an identity column. Could not create constraint

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-5, fluent

I'm working on an Entity Framework 5 Code First project. Right now I'm gettcannot be createding the error:

```
"Cascading foreign key 'FK_dbo.DriverLicense_dbo.Person_PersonId' where the referencing column 'DriverLicense.PersonId' is an identity column.\r\nCould not create constraint
```

These are my entities, Why I'm getting that error? I'm not saying PersonId is identity there in DriverLicense entity.

```
public class DriverLicense
{
    public long DriverLicenseId { get; set; }
    public long LicenseNumber { get; set; }
    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class DriverLicenseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DriverLicense>
{
        public DriverLicenseMap()
        {
            this.HasKey(t => t.DriverLicenseId);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("DriverLicense");
            this.Property(t => t.DriverLicenseId).HasColumnName("DriverLicenseId");
            this.Property(t => t.LicenseNumber).HasColumnName("LicenseNumber");
            this.Property(t => t.PersonId).HasColumnName("PersonId");

            this.HasRequired(t => t.Person)
                .WithMany(t => t.DriverLicenses)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId);

        }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.DriverLicenses = new List<DriverLicense>();
    }

    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DriverLicense> DriverLicenses { get; set; }
}

 public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.PersonId);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.LastName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Person");
            this.Property(t => t.PersonId).HasColumnName("PersonId");
            this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
            this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");

        }
```

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

**EDIT:** With SQL Profiler I can see this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DriverLicense] (
    [DriverLicenseId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [LicenseNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.DriverLicense] PRIMARY KEY ([DriverLicenseId])
)
```

**I do not understand why PersonId is created as Identity**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the problem.
I'm using Migrations, and there was one pending which had the wrong model.
So, if you're in the same situation, check your pending migrations! :)
Thanks! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem:

you must change this `public long PersonId { get; set; }` property to `public long? PersonId { get; set; }`

because when you try to add for first time, a new DriverLicense you can't assign DriverLicense.PersonId to any object (because you don't have any Person for assign) **so** you must set PersonId property to nullable.

**edit:**
[this link can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034896/when-an-entity-has-more-than-one-0-1n-relationships-to-another-enitity-how-to)