# When an entity has more than one 0..1:n relationships to another entity, how to define them using Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-mobile-services, ef-fluent-api

I'm working on an Azure Mobile Service and in my model I have an entity **Message**, which is related to itself following this statement:

- A **Message** may have a parent **Message**, a **Message** may be the parent to many **Messages**.

My class got defined as follows:

```
public partial class Message
{
    public Message()
    {
        this.Messages = new HashSet<Message>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public int RecipientId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int MessageTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<MessageType> Type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Draft { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Read { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Replied { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isDeleted { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual User Recipient { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Message Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And my DTO is this:

```
public class MessageDTO : EntityData 
{
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Draft { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Read { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Replied { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

I mapped this two classes using AutoMapper like this:

```
        /*
         * Mapping for Message entity
         */
        cfg.CreateMap<Message, MessageDTO>()
            .ForMember(messageDTO => messageDTO.Id, map => map.MapFrom(message => MySqlFuncs.LTRIM(MySqlFuncs.StringConvert(message.Id))))
            .ForMember(messageDTO => messageDTO.ParentId, map => map.MapFrom(message => MySqlFuncs.LTRIM(MySqlFuncs.StringConvert(message.ParentId))))
            .ForMember(messageDTO => messageDTO.CreatedById , map => map.MapFrom(message => MySqlFuncs.LTRIM(MySqlFuncs.StringConvert(message.CreatedById ))))
            .ForMember(messageDTO => messageDTO.RecipientId, map => map.MapFrom(message => MySqlFuncs.LTRIM(MySqlFuncs.StringConvert(message.RecipientId))))
            .ForMember(messageDTO => messageDTO.Type, map => map.MapFrom(message => Enum.GetName(typeof(MessageType), message.MessageTypeId)));

        cfg.CreateMap<MessageDTO, Message>()
            .ForMember(message => message.Id, map => map.MapFrom(messageDTO => MySqlFuncs.LongParse(messageDTO.Id)))
            .ForMember(message => message.ParentId, map => map.MapFrom(messageDTO => MySqlFuncs.LongParse(messageDTO.ParentId)))
            .ForMember(message => message.CreatedById , map => map.MapFrom(messageDTO => MySqlFuncs.LongParse(messageDTO.CreatedById )))
            .ForMember(message => message.RecipientId, map => map.MapFrom(messageDTO => MySqlFuncs.LongParse(messageDTO.RecipientId)));
```

And my Fluent API configuration for this is:

```
        this.Property(m => m.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.HasRequired(m => m.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Messages).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        this.HasRequired(m => m.Recipient).WithMany(u => u.MessagesReceived).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.HasRequired(m => m.CreatedBy).WithMany(u => u.MessagesCreated).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But when I try to insert a new Message I get the following error:

> The operation failed with the following error: 'Entities in
>   'MobileServiceContext.Messages' participate in the 'Message_CreatedBy'
>   relationship. 0 related 'Message_CreatedBy_Target' were found. 1
>   'Message_CreatedBy_Target' is expected.

From this error I'm understanding that my **Message** is expecting to have a *Parent*, but since this would be the first **Message** there's no *Parent*, also not every **Message** will have a parent. In my *Fluent API* configuration I defined the *Parent* property as required, because when I set it to optional, when trying to insert a **Message** I got the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model
>   generation:FollowAppApi.Models.Message_Parent: : Multiplicity
>   conflicts with the referential constraint in Role
>   'Message_Parent_Target' in relationship 'Message_Parent'. Because all
>   of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity
>   of the Principal Role must be '1'.

The JSON I'm sending to the endpoint is the following:

```
{
  "createdById": "1",
  "recipientId": "2",
  "title": "sample string 4",
  "content": "sample string 5",
  "type": "Alert",
  "draft": true,
  "read": true,
  "replied": true,
  "isDeleted": false
}
```

How can I set my configuration to define an optional property in this scenario or any other where an option property should be present?

### EDIT 1

So I checked and [read this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) when dealing with a situation where an entity has two relationships with other entity, I added the InverseProperty annotations and got the following error:

> The operation failed with the following error: 'Unable to determine a
>   valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to
>   foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated
>   values.

From what I remember, this error refers to a circular reference being present, I guess it's from either the Parent property or maybe either of the User relationships with Message, but I'm not really sure.

What is the cause for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the following error:

> The operation failed with the following error: 'Unable to determine a
>   valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to
>   foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated
>   values.

Is due to the Parent property in message not being nullable. Take notice this is on the Model class, not the DTO, since string is already a nullable type.

So in Message I had to change:

```
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
```

for this:

```
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
```

And this allows me to insert Messages on my POST endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

When you have self referencing objects, you need to provide the Foreign Key property manually.

`this.HasOptional(m => m.Parent)
    .WithMany(p => p.Messages)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.ParentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`

Comment: I realized my error was a different one from what I thought, so I changed the title to reflect this